# Martingale +OST voting question

Tags: probability, martingales

In ellections between two candidates candidate A got $a$ number of votes and B got $b$ number of votes. It is given that $a>b$, assuming the votes were counted uniformly show that the probability that candidate A led over candidate B across the counting process equals to: $\frac{a-b}{a+b}$.

This is what I did so far:
1) define $S_k$ which will be the difference between "a" and "b" votes after "k" counted votes.
2) show that $X_k = \frac{S_a+b-k}{a+b-k}$ is martingale.
3) use the SOT and show that $E(X_0)=E(X_T)$ hence equal to $\frac{a-b}{a+b}$

I'm facing difficulties with showing that $X_k = \frac{S_a+b-k}{a+b-k}$ is martingale.

Here is what I tried:

$$E(X_{k+1} \mid X_0,\dots,X_k) = E(X_{k} + B_{k+1} \mid X_0,\dots,X_k)$$

where:

$B_{k+1}$ 
is if "a"/"b"  vote was counted at the k+1 step

Thank you for helping :)

Comment: The ballot theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand's_ballot_theorem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a > b$ and $n = a + b$ with $S_k = $ the number of votes A is leading by after $k$ votes counted. Then $S_n = a - b$ and $X_k = \frac{S_{n  - k}}{n - k}$ for $0 \leq k \leq n - 1$. To show $X_k$ is a martingale we have to find

$$E[X_k|X_0,...,X_{k-1}] = E\bigg[\frac{S_{n  - k}}{n - k}|S_n,...,S_{n-k+1}\bigg]$$

First let $a_k$ = number of votes for A after $k$ votes are counted and $b_k$ = number of votes for B after $k$ votes are counted. We have that

$$a_{n-k+1} = \frac{n - k + 1 + S_{n - k + 1}}{2}$$
$$b_{n-k+1} = \frac{n - k + 1 - S_{n - k + 1}}{2}$$
and 
$$
S_{n-k} =
\begin{cases}
S_{n - k + 1} + 1 \quad \text{if n - k + 1 vote is for B} \\
S_{n - k + 1} - 1 \quad \text{if n - k + 1 vote is for A}
\end{cases}
$$

This leads to 
$$E[S_{n  - k}|S_{n-k+1}] = (S_{n-k+1} + 1)\frac{a_{n - k + 1}}{(n - k + 1)} + (S_{n-k+1} - 1)\frac{b_{n - k + 1}}{(n - k + 1)}$$

$$E[S_{n  - k}|S_{n-k+1}] = S_{n-k+1}\frac{n - k}{n - k + 1}$$

and back to the original expectation we have
$$E[X_k|X_0,...,X_{k-1}] = E\bigg[\frac{S_{n  - k}}{n - k}|S_n,...,S_{n-k+1}\bigg] = \frac{S_{n - k + 1}}{n - k + 1} = X_{k-1}$$

We have that $X_k$ is a martingale. By the martingale stopping theorem we have
$$E[X_T] = E[X_0] = \frac{E[S_n]}{n}$$

Comment: I don't believe I had a minus mistake! thank you! just one question: $$E[S_{n  - k}|S_{n-k+1}]$$ doesn't the notation should be opposite $n-k+1$ is one step after $n-k$ so $n-k$ is given when you try to show that martingale process exists.

Comment: Conditioning on $X_0, X_1,...,X_{k−1}$ is equivalent to conditioning on $S_n, S_{n−1},...,S_{n−k+1}$ which is conditioning on values of count when counting the $k − 1$ last votes.

Comment: ok ok now I got it! thank you very much!